# How to use a parameter as datasource location in context.xml?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have my database url hardcoded in my context.xml (tomcat 7):

```
<Context path="">
    <Resource name="jdbc/MyDataSource" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:mysql://my.database:3306/ebdb"/>

    <!-- Realm and other cfg--> 
</Context>
```

And that points to a different host in each environment (dev/test/production/etc...)

Would it be possible to have it set as a parameter or environment variable, so developers don't need to add it manually to their hosts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${propname}` syntax to refer to the system property in your context.xml.

context.xml:

`url="jdbc:mysql://${propname}:3306/ebdb"`

VM argument:

`-Dpropname=yourhost`

Please refer to the following document for tomcat's ${propname} syntax support:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is great and almost does the trick.. would it be possible to default to localhost? (shooting for zero conf)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to set the default value.